# Ocaml count trie elements

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, trie

I'm trying to find how many characters i have in my Trie.

This is my Trie type.

```
type 'a t = Node of 'a list * ('a arc list) 
and 'a arc = char * 'a t
```

This is my implementation that is not exhaustive:

```
let arc_size trie =
  let rec count_arcs counter trie =
    match trie with
    | Node (_,[]) -> counter
    | Node (_,[(_,x)] -> count_arcs (counter+1) trie
  in
  count_arcs 0 trie;;
```

This would work if the trie contained only 1 word. The problem is if the trie branches out and one of the nodes has this type `Node(_,[(_,x)] :: _ :: _)`

I can't seem to find a match pattern for this case since if i match the trie with Node(_,x) the x in this case is `a arc list` but my function has a trie as argument. I'm having trouble branching out towards the other `'a arcs` in my `'a arc list`.

Comment: You need to apply the recursive `count_arcs` function to every element of the sublist (see  `List.map`) then sum all the results together (one way to do it would be using `List.fold_left`).

Comment: I did try this at some point and that's where i ran into the issue i described last. If i do a pattern match to retrieve my list like this `| Node(_,x)` i can then apply the function to all the elements of the list, except that i can't. My function takes `'a t` as argument while the list has `char * 'a t` elements. This is what blocked me initially.

Answer (score 1):

You shall call your `count_arcs` function recursively on each subarc of the node (you're calling it recursively on the same trie which remains invariant during recursion, thus your function will never terminate if it hit the second branch of your example).

You can rely on [List.fold_left](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALfold_left) and for a node `x` that has a list of arcs `xs` define the number of arcs as a sum of the number of arcs each arc in `xs` has, plus the number of arcs that `x` has.

Alternatively, you can use pattern-matching and manually deconstruct the list of arcs, but it is better to split the complex task into small subtasks and then combine them. If you're not allowed to use the functions from the standard library (for didactic purposes) then it is a good time to implement your own `fold` function.